# Choose AS400 query records directly from Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, database-connection, ibm-midrange

I've been searching the internet for hours trying to figure out if the following is even possible:
To choose the AS400 query records directly from Excel.

I haven't found any solution or description of how this could be achieved, which makes me guess that it's simply not possible. However, I haven't seen anyone confirm that it is impossible.
So my question is: Is this possible? And if it is, could you point me in the right direction in order for me to start learning how to do it?

I know its possible to run a query from Excel, and then adding parameters via SQL statements, but in my case, this presents several problems that could be avoided by choosing the records before the query is executed.

**Example**:
I have a query with a column (lets call it `ColVal`) that can hold the values 1 and/or 2. In the AS400 program under the menu "Work with queries" and then "Choose records" I can specify which records the query should contain when it has run based on the value in `ColVal`. This means i can get three different situations (A, B and C) when i run the query:

A) The query only contains records where the value in `ColVal` is 1
B) The query only contains records where the value in `ColVal` is 2
C) The query contains records where the value in `ColVal` is either 1 or 2

The goal is to be able to choose which situation I want from Excel in order to circumvent opening and using the AS400 program.
**However,** using situation C and then editing the query in Excel with an SQL statement to mimic situation A or B is not an option, as this means the query still contains undesired records.

This whole thing boils down to the following: Is it even possible to run the query from Excel essentially changing the data it contains and not just outputting it to excel? If this is possible, is it then possible to pass a parameter to the AS400 system and use it to create situation A, B or C?

I hope this example makes sense.

**Edit - New example**

Say i have different customers A and B. I can open the AS400 program and run a query in which i have specified that I only want data on customer A. I can then open Excel and use filters (as Hambone described) on the query to determine which records I want to output. However, if I want to work with data from customer B, I have to open the AS400 again and run the query with different parameters. I would like to be able to "change" my dataset from customer A to B from Excel, without having to include both in my recordset and then filter out one of them.

I imagined this is doable if you could pass a parameter to the AS400. The AS400 then runs the query using this parameter as the criteria for which records should be stored in the query. This means that if the parameter is Customer B, then there is no way to acces data from customer A, without running the query through AS400 again.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I suspect not also, but do you have an example?  How could you "choose" records before actually fetching them, or do you mean based on criteria, similar to a where clause?

Comment: @Hambone Thanks for your reply - unfortunately I don't have any examples, which is why I suspect it's impossible. I'm not sure what to call it other than "choose". It would be like opening the AS400 program and using the "Work with queries" function, except it's done from Excel. My idea was to build a `Userform` in Excel and then prompt the user for different inputs. Then use these inputs as the criteria for which records should be fetched from the query in AS400. Does this make sense? :)

Comment: I think I understand.  In that case, I think you could use Microsoft Query with an ODBC connection to DB2.  You may have to do some dynamic SQL to accommodate optional parameters.  If this sounds like it's on track, and you need an example, I can probably come up with one.

Comment: @Hambone This definitely sounds interesting. I've already messed about a bit with Power Query in Excel and I already have a working ODBC connection (I think at least). However, i couldn't find a way to change the parameters in the query before the query was executed. I could only choose which columns I wanted to include in my output table via SQL statements. If you could produce an example for me to see, that would be awesome and greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: @Hambone And for the record - I have no experience with database connections or SQL. So if I'm bad at explaining my situation or findings, that is probably the reason. Don't be shy to correct me or to ask for a better explanation - I'm eager to learn :)

Comment: Don't know if I answered the mail or not, but I made an edit below per your latest comment

Comment: @Hambone Again thank you so much for taking the time to help me out! It is greatly appreciated! :) However, I think I'm bad at explaining my problem, so let me try in another way. I've edited my question to include another example

Comment: Wow, I almost wish we could walk through this because based on your example, I thought the solution before did what you seek...  but that probably means I still don't understand.  The solution as described does a filter at the database level, meaning Excel itself is oblivious to any content other than what is passed via the query.  You can, of course, filter it after the fact, but that's not what the parameter actually does.  This may be asking a lot, but can you include the table name/structure, sample data,, filter condition(s) and expected result(s) as a test condition?

Comment: @Hambone Thank you for being so patient with me - like I said, it can very well be me, who doesn't fully understand your solution, and not you, who don't fully understand my problem ;) Is there perhaps a chat system or something similar, like discord we could use to step through it? Also then i would be able to supply you with the extra details you requested :)

Answer (score 7):

Follow up to my comment, here is a quick primer on how to run an ODBC query directly in MS Excel using Microsoft Query.  This is very different than Power Query, which you referenced, in that MS Query is standard with Excel -- it's not a plug-in.  This is relevant because it means everyone has it.  If you are deploying a solution to others, that's an important consideration.

To start an MS Query in Excel, go to the data tab, select "From Other Sources" -> "Microsoft Query."

[image]

A list of your ODBC connections will come up.  Pick the one that you want and select "OK."

[image]

It may or may not ask you for a login (depending on which ODBC connection you use and how its configured).

[image]

The next part is important.  MS Query is going to try to have you use its builder to create the query.  If you have the SQL, skip this part.  It's horrible.  Click "Cancel" on the query wizard, and then click the "SQL" button to enter your own SQL.  If you can, make sure the result set is small (like use `where 1 = 2` in the query).

[image]

When MS Query returns results, click the button next to the SQL Button to have it return the results to the spreadsheet.  It looks like a little door.

From here, any time you want to refresh the query, you can simply right-click the data table in Excel and select "refresh."  Alternatively you can go to the data tab on the ribbon and select "Refresh."

By the way if you have linked pivot tables and charts, the "Refresh All" option will refresh those as well, in the correct order.

To edit your query at any time, right-click on the table in Excel, go to Table-External Data Properties:

[image]

Then Click on the Connection Properties icon (highlighted below)

[image]

Click on the second tab (Definition) and edit the SQL Directly.

Parameters can be declared simply by inserting a bare "?" in place of your literal.

In other words, if your query looks like this:

```
select *
from users
where user_id = 'hambone'
```

Just change it to:

```
select *
from users
where user_id = ?
```

Excel will prompt you for a user id before it runs the query.  From here, you also have the option of putting the parameter value in a cell within the spreadsheet and having the query read it from there.  You'll see these when you right-click the table and go to the "Parameters" menu option.

[image]

Let me know if this helps or is unclear.

-- EDIT 7/23/2018 --

To follow up on your latest edit, it is possible to handle the scenario you describe, where you want to be able to filter on a value, or if none is given, then not have a filter.  You see this a lot when you present multiple filter options to the user and you want a blank to mean "no filter," which is obviously counter to the way SQL works.

However, you can hack SQL to still make it work:

```
select * from activities
where
 (activity = ? or ? is null) and
 (energy = ? or ? is null)
```

In this example you have to declare four parameters instead of two, two for each.

You might also have to play with datatypes, depending on the RDBMS (for example for numerics you might have to say `? = 0` instead of `? is null` or even `? = ''` for text).

Here is a working example where a single filter was applied on the query above and you can clearly see the second one did not have an impact.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain all this. Unfortunately I only have acces to the database from my workplace, which means I won't be able to test this until Monday. I've already got several of these tables, that are linked to the database and able to be refreshed like you explained. What i haven't tried, is using the question marks to get the parameters. I will definitely try that on Monday and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: I might have done this wrongly, but it looks like this doesn't solve my problem unfortunately. When I insert the question mark as you explained, it does indeed prompt for a parameter. This parameter is then used to determine which records to fetch from the query. In my case i need to run the query again with that parameter from the database. I've included an example in my question that might explain this a bit better. Thank you for your help again - I hope you still have some ideas I can try out :)

Comment: I do this technique in Excel all the time (using an ODBC data source not MS Query), but not with parameters. I am usually either manually editing the SQL statement with a parameter, or if the data set is small enough, run it with no where clause and use Excel filters to narrow it down.

Comment: @Mike -- I'm very interested.  Is there a way to do this directly with an SQL statement that is not a simple table or view?  I've done this through ODBC directly as well, but I never found a way to use a complex query.  Or, do you select a trivial table to start with and edit the SQL after the fact?  Also, check out the parameter and the "Refresh Excel Automatically" flag.  It's pretty handy.

Comment: "select a trivial table to start with and edit the SQL after the fact"  **exactly**  Excel may give a dialog box saying that the connection has changed, you just agree.  Then you can edit the SQL any number of times and it will update your table.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible. You need to use an ODBC driver to connect to the AS400 and retrieve the data. The driver and documentation are [Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzaik/rzaikappodbc.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much - this is definitely a step in the right direction. I'm a complete coding noob, so i will have to spend some time looking into this. If i find that the link you provided solves my problem, i will promptly accept your answer :)

Comment: There is a lot of information in this link, but I think it might be a bit too advanced for me to understand. I can't figure out if there is a way to achieve what i want through VBA alone or if you need additional programs. Can elaborate a bit on how you know it's possible? :)