# c# Exported Excel file from gridview is having header size issue

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export

I am exporting gridview data to excel file. The excel file has only TWO column.
I have set header color to PINK. But this PINK[image: Here is my Output file] color is set to entire row of that header instead of only two column.

Here is my code...

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=User_Log.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/excel ";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

myConn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select User_id , LoginDate from LoginLog where LoginDate between
                                ('" + TextBox1.Text + "') and ('" + ToDate + "')", myConn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;

GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
myConn.Close();
```

Comment: Might I suggest rather than writing a C# application from scratch if all you want is  a spreadsheet with output of a query, try using MS Excel's fantastic MS Query.  It does everything you seek and connects natively to SQL Server.  You don't even need VBA.  Here is a link to a similar question for AS400, but you can just use SQL Server instead of ODBC, and everything else will virtually be cut and paste.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51437286/choose-as400-query-records-directly-from-excel/51444029#51444029