# Excel Add Query Method

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

The following works great on my computer but fails on a colleague's computer:

```
    GetUserName = Environ$("username")

    If GetUserName = "user1" Then
        o_dsn = """dsn=mydbs"""
    Else
        o_dsn = """dsn=dbs2"""
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Query1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Odbc.Query(" & o_dsn & ", ""Select InvoiceNo, EffectDate from " & _
            "batchcontract " & _
            "where InvoiceNo in( " & _
            RangeToString & _
            ") """ & _
        ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source" & _
        ""
```

His machine is failing with "Object Doesn't Support Property or Method" error on the "Queries.Add" statement.  We're both running Office 365 ProPlus on Windows 10 and are using the same Excel references.  While our DSNs carry different labels, both point to the same MySQL DB, have credentials saved in the ODBC definition and pass a connection test.

I'm not sure if Excel is objecting to the "Queries.Add" method, or the "Odbc.Query" clause.  Can anyone clarify the reason for this error?  Any ideas would be welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run this query on your colleague's machine without using VBA (i.e. setting it up manually with Power Query)? Is an error thrown in the query editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ODBC, the name of the connection seems to matter a lot.  On the flip side, I've found all you really need is the DSN, and it will pull back any connection details based on the way you've set up the connection.

That said, you appear to have that handled in your if/then.

I've never used queries in the way you list -- I always do them as tables within a workseet.  In that spirit, here is a quick and dirty boilerplate for how I add a table through VBA.  This is essentially the VBA way to do what is listed in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444029/1278553

Try this -- on both machines -- and see if they both work with the respectively named DNS.

```
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set lo = ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, _
  Source:=Array(Array("ODBC;DSN=mydbs")), _
  Destination:=Range("A1"))
lo.QueryTable.CommandText = "select foo from bar"
lo.Refresh
```

Also, is there any harm in adding an ODBC connection with a matching name?

Comment: I adopted your approach and abandoned the Queries.Add step.  Filling a list object directly with the query result worked consistently, rather than directly addressing Excel's query facility.  Should have been coding under KISS principals anyway.  Thanks!