# Excel Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

Connect SQL Server via Excel

Can connect to SQL Server via Excel using

> Excel -> Data -> From Other Sources -> From SQL Server.

I tried to connect same SQL Server via

> Excel -> Data -> New Query -> From Database -> From SQL Server

and it didn't work
I need to extract data based on query hence taking query route.

Comment: Check out this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51437286/choose-as400-query-records-directly-from-excel/51444029#51444029.  It references AS400, but it's basically the same; just a different data source

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Data | Get Data | From Database | From SQL Server Database as can be seen below:

[image: Get Data]

Specify your SQL Instance and the Database you require to connect to.

Click on Advanced Options and paste your query as can be seen below:

[image: Data]

Click on OK.

Your data is previewed as following:

[image: Preview]

Click on Load and your data is loaded...

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks however I tried above route and it didn;t work. It didn;t give me enough details to what's causing the issue. There is just error message "Unable to Logon". any idea how to investigate on error

Comment: Do you know if your ports, etc. is open on your SQL? Please consider going through the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502714/intermittent-odbc-connection-failures/52504914#52504914), which will guide you on how to properly setup your SQL Server...